# mechanize keeps giving URLErrors

Tags: python, http, screen-scraping, web-scraping, mechanize

I'm automating some stuff with mechanize. I have a working program that logs into a site and goes to a page while logged in. However, sometimes I just get `URLError`s stating the connection has timed out, whenever I do anything via mechanize:

```
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>
```

If I restart the program or re-try the attempts, it will just work. If I visit the same site with Chrome, it will never time out, no matter how often I attempt to log in.

What might be the cause of this? It sounds like mechanize is doing something that isn't ideal. I've gotten a similar pattern with different sites as well - `URLError`s when there are in fact no connection issues.

EDIT: I also notice that if I do this - retry immediately - it often works, but then will fail again on the next thing I do, etc.

```
last_response = ...
for attempt in (1, 2):
    try:
        self.mech.select_form(nr=0)
        self.mech[self.LOGIN_FORM_DATA[1]] = self.user
        self.mech[self.LOGIN_FORM_DATA[2]] = self.password
        resp = self.mech.submit()
        html = resp.read()
        resp.close()
    except mechanize.URLError:
        self.error("URLError submitting form, trying again...")
        self.mech.set_response(last_response) #reset the response 
        continue
    break
```

Comment: I am experiencing a very similar issue with a program that polls a website every 2 hours or so. It seems to occur after the program has been running for some time (I rarely restart my Windows 7 PC) or after the laptop being put to sleep a couple of times. Restarting the program makes everything run fine again. I've recently did some additional investigation using the BurpSuite intercept proxy, and it seems the answer (i.e., the html response) really got through. But somehow mechanize reports a timeout. I've added some extra debug code and am waiting for the issue to appear again.

Comment: BTW: I've also tried the "retry" approach earlier, which is sometimes working, sometimes not...